# How do I make a policy to stop inserting a row if two values from the table are the same as the values I plan to insert

Tags: database, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I need to check if a booking with the same timestamp and product id has been made before inserting a new row.

I am struggling with making this policy and would be great if anybody could help.

Here is the schema for my table:

```
create table Bookings (
  id bigint not null primary key,
  created_at timestamp default now(),
  start timestamp default now(),
  name character,
  user_id uuid,
  notes text,
  product_id bigint references Services (id),
  status text not null,
  owner_id uuid default uuid_generate_v4()
);
```

I have tried using triggers with no luck and I made a function to check if there is a row with the same timestamp and product id with timestamp and product is as input and a bool as output. At first I was thinking I could use this in the policy but I received some errors that the function didn't exist.

```
create or replace function same_time_bookings(bookingtime timestamp, product int) 
returns boolean
as
$$
declare
  returnbool boolean;
begin
  SELECT case when COUNT(*) > 0 
            then 0
            else 1
       end into returnbool from "Bookings" where 
  product_id = product
  and extract(year from start) = extract(year from bookingtime)
  and extract(month from start) = extract(month from bookingtime)
  and extract(day from start) = extract(day from bookingtime)
  and extract(hour from start) = extract(hour from bookingtime);
  return returnbool;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why not just make a `UNIQUE` index on (product_id, timestamp)?

Comment: Because then I would not be able to have the same time on two bookings on different products. For example if I am booking product **product A** at 12/06/22 10:00 it should also be possible to book **product B** at 12/06/22 10:00 but it should not be possible to book **product A**  again at 12/06/22 10:00 pm

Comment: No, the two-column unique constraint  would prevent two rows where *both* columns are the same.

Comment: If product A and product B have different `product_id`'s  then you can do just that. Also I don't see how my suggestion is different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Sorry I'm just new to PostgreSQL and didn't know what unique index was.

Comment: You might want to, as update to your question, explain further ` product A at 12/06/22 10:00` and  `product A at 12/06/22 10:00 pm`. Does the first instance mean ` product A at 12/06/22 10:00 am`? If so the `UNIQUE` index will not catch that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a unique constraint for 2 columns `product_id` and `start`. This way you can have multiple rows with the same product_id but different timestamps.

```
create table Bookings (
  id bigint not null primary key,
  created_at timestamp default now(),
  start timestamp default now(), 
  product_id bigint,
  UNIQUE (product_id, start) -- Add this
);
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bb25b8eaf3d594141c6d54f95f0e8238)